# Discord currency bot SyntaxError

Tags: python, syntax-error

I was programming a discord currency bot in python when I got a `SyntaxError` from this line:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = c!)
```

Any ideas on what it could be?

Comment: Please include more context of the code and a full error traceback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to store the `command_prefix` argument in a string using quotes:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='c!')
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `c!` is invalid because `!` is only used in Python as part of a not equals operator, `!=` (see [operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators)).